# Mongo doesn't restore user password

Tags: backup, mongodb, restore, mongodb-3.6

I have following scenario:

1. Dump Mongo database (cmd mongodump)
2. Change password from one of admin users
3. Restore Mongo database (cmd mongorestore)

**EDIT:**

I use following command for db dump:

```
mongodump -h $HOST:$PORT --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --authenticationDatabase $authdb -u $user -p $pass --gzip --archive=$destination
```

As a result password was not restored. Is there any defect plan that can be followed in mongodb for this specific case?

Answer (score 1):

So I found solution, --drop shoud be added in the command:

```
mongodump -h $HOST:$PORT --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --authenticationDatabase $authdb -u $user -p $pass --drop --gzip --archive=$destination
```